# Javascript String Manipulation and Conversion with Range

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, data-manipulation

I have a string like this (must be in this format):

```
var string = "[0] No new notifications | [1,] Some new notifications"
```

And I want to get "No new notifications" if a variable is 0 and if that variable is 1 or greater, show "Some new notifications".

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show your snippet ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? For example, with your string shown above, what would be the result? Also, do you really intend to have a comma after the 1?

Comment: `(myVar > 0 ? "Some" : "No") + " new notifications"`

Comment: @JonathanM The string is in this format because it's in a locale file for i18n-node, `i18n.__n("%s new notification", notis)`. The comma is there to tell i18n that anything that is one or greater should show "Some new notifications". My problem is that my client side i18n doesn't recognize this format, so I have to add a custom function or parse this somehow...

Comment: @Michał, I'm not following. What would be the result from your string above?

Comment: @JonathanM See [this](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node#ranged-interval-support).

Comment: @JonathanM The result should be what both IrkenInvader and myself have posted

Comment: @mhodges, yes I saw what you posted, but I also saw it had not been accepted, so I'm asking the OP what he's really after.

Comment: @Michał Take a look at my updated solution, I think it is exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic processesor for ISO 31-11 strings. It takes the ISO 31-11 string and the numeric value, then returns the appropriate string or undefined. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2g1oa8a/3/).

```
function processISO31_11(rangeGuide, n) {
  var separator = /\[(\d+)(,)?(\d+)?\]\s?(.+)/;
  var rangeGuides = rangeGuide.split('|');
  var guideCount = rangeGuides.length;
  for (var guide = 0; guide < guideCount; guide++) {
    var elements = separator.exec(rangeGuides[guide]);
    if (elements != null) {
      if (n < parseFloat(elements[1])) {
        return; // return undefined indicating failure to match any range
      }
      if (n == parseFloat(elements[1])) {
        return elements[4];
      }
        if (elements[2] === "," && (typeof elements[3] === "undefined" || n <= parseFloat(elements[3]))) {
        return elements[4];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Clean, short, and concise! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After examining more closely exactly what you are looking for, I have come up with a solution that will read in the rules you pass it and essentially turn that into logic that your program will follow. Here is a demo of how it would work:

```js
var myVar = 3;
var myStr = '[0] No new notifications | [1,4] Some new notifications | [5,] Several new notifications';
var notificationRules = getRules(myStr);

function getRules(rulesString) {
  return rulesString.split(' | ').map(function(rule) {
    var startValue, endValue;
    var values = rule.match(/\[\d*,?\d*\]/g)[0];
    values = values.replace(/\[|\]/g, "").split(",");
    startValue = values[0];
    endValue = +values[1] === 0 ? Infinity : values[1];
    return {
      startValue: Number(startValue),
      endValue: endValue != undefined ? Number(endValue) : undefined,
      message: rule.replace(/\[\d*,?\d*\]/g, "").trim()
    };
  });
}

function getMessage(myVar, rules) {
  var message = "No rule match!";
  rules.some(function(rule) {
    if (myVar === rule.startValue) {
      message = rule.message;
      return true;
    } else if (myVar >= rule.startValue && myVar <= rule.endValue) {
      message = rule.message;
    }
  });
  return message;
}

console.log(getMessage(0, notificationRules));
console.log(getMessage(2, notificationRules));
console.log(getMessage(5, notificationRules));
console.log(getMessage(100, notificationRules));
console.log(getMessage(-1, notificationRules));
```

Comment: Looks, and functions great! Just had to add a check to see if there even was a `[0]` or similar declaration, but nothing major. Do you think this could be optimised somehow by using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

```
var somevar = 3;
var yourString = '[0] No new notifications | [1,] Some new notifications';
var notification = yourString .split(' | ');
var message=(somevar == 0 ? notification[0].split('] ')[1] : notification[1].split('] ')[1]);
```

the var message has your needed output.

Comment: Works great for my specific example! Many thanks! The only thing that I could possibly mention is that this doesn't seem to account for more ranges like `[0] No new notifications | [1,2] Some new notifications | [3,] Too many notifications`

Answer (score 0):

Complex solution using `String.prototype.split()`, `String.prototype.match()` and `String.prototype.slice()` functions:

```js
var configStr = '[0] No new notifications | [1,] Some new notifications',
    getNotifyMessage = function (config, num) {
        var num = Number(num),
            items = config.split('|'), 
            len = items.length, parts;

        while (len--) {
            parts = items[len].match(/\[(\d+,?)\]\s([\w ]+)(?=\||$)/i);
            if (Number(parts[1]) === num) {
                return parts[2];
            }
            if (parts[1].slice(-1) === ',' && Number(parts[1].slice(0,-1)) <= num) {
                return parts[2];  
            }
        }

        return '';
  };

console.log(getNotifyMessage(configStr, 1));
console.log(getNotifyMessage(configStr, 0));
console.log(getNotifyMessage(configStr, 3));
```